# How to include / require `use` operator statements?

Tags: php, laravel, class, namespaces

I dynamically generate my use statements and try to include them.

**use.php** (Path: /App/Test/Use/use.php)

```
<?php
    use App\Http\Utility\GeneralUtility;
    use App\Models\Project;
    use App\Http\Selenium;
?>
```

**PlayController.php** (Path: /App/Http/Controllers/PlayController.php)

```
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;
    require app_path() . '\Projects\Test\Use\use.php';
    ...
```

However, If I try to use a included/required class in my controller then I get the info that some classes are missing. E.g.

```
FatalThrowableError in PlayController.php line 30:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Selenium' not found
```

Of course it works If I write them manually into the Controller without using `require`:

```
<?php
    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\Http\Utility\GeneralUtility;
    use App\Models\Project;
    use App\Http\Selenium;

    ...
```

So why does it not work if I include / require them?

Comment: No, it works if I write the use statements manually above the class. So the error must be related to the include/require.

Comment: Do they all give that error, or just that one?

Comment: It will maybe a stupid comment, but could be that 'use' is to make PHP using classes, and include just for including them.

Comment: All gives error, so it looks like PHP is not capable of including use statements.

Comment: Yes, I've tested it. I believe it's just not possible... I'm not the best expert on here though, I'll try to find the documentation quote on this.

Comment: What a pitty, I was about to create an awesome project, but I can't because this is not possible.

Comment: No I think there isn't, I dynamically generate my use statements. If a new model is added then I generate a class for it and I have to create an alias for this new class in a specific controller. Now I have to do this by hand because it is not possible with PHP to include use statements.

Comment: Yes, that sounds somewhat impossible... Let me think about it for a bit, I might come up with something.

Comment: Use a makefile, use `cat` to prepend your file before deployment...

Comment: I found a more intelligent way, I just create the controller dynamically too now, then I have full control during the creation process and can include all aliases which I need. It has some disadvantages and you have to do many checks tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is **not** possible what you are trying to do. 
Here is the *documentation* from the PHP manual on it:

> **Note:** Importing rules are per file basis, meaning included files will **NOT** inherit the parent file's importing rules.

The source comes from [**here**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php#example-257) and the full documentation link is [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php).

Answer (score 1):

Use is done at compile time and include at runtime, so that makes it impossible.
But what you could do is, use something like [PHP-Parser](https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser) to replace the includes before the script is being executed.

Comment: Yes, that would be possible. Is it clean? *No* absolutly not.... It's the only way I suppose..

Comment: I hope they will implement a feature in the future so that it will be possible to include use statements, this would bring so many new possiblities